# Why is my ball losing energy when it bounces?

Tags: python, game-physics

As a bit of an exercise I've been trying to follow a Java tutorial while converting it to python, as it makes me think a bit more than just copying what the tutorial types on the screen.

I'm up to this part of the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuqCfxZcFCI&list=PL87AA2306844063D2&index=6

He makes a ball drop from y = 25, hit the bottom of the window and bounce up, using physics formulae v = u+at and s = s+vt + 1/2at^2.
He then shows that because the ball doesn't lose energy when it hits the ground, it always returns to the same height it was dropped from. To fix this, he adds an energy loss formula.

So I recreated his code in python, but as I was testing it, I noticed that even without the energy loss formula, my ball behaves more like a real life ball, bouncing lower and lower each time.

Can anyone spot what's causing this? Thanks!

```
import pygame

# pygame window
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ball Game!")
FPS = 60

# physics variables
GRAVITY = 15
ENERGY_LOSS = 0.65
dt = 0.2

# player position variables
x = 400
y = 25
dx = 0
dy = 0
radius = 20

#colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

def draw_window():
    WINDOW.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.circle(WINDOW, GREEN, (x, y), radius)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    global x
    global y
    global dx
    global dy
    run = True

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        if y > HEIGHT-radius-1:
            y = HEIGHT - radius - 1
            # dy = dy * ENERGY_LOSS # Why is there energy loss without the formula!?!?!
            dy = -dy
        else:
            # velocity- acceleration formula
            dy += GRAVITY * dt
            # position formula
            y += dy * dt + (0.5 * GRAVITY * dt ** 2)

        draw_window()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For one, if your ball is lower than the floor when it bounces, it loses the energy it used to go lower than the floor, since you reset it to exactly the floor instead of reflecting it across the floor or something.

Comment: @Ry- doesn't it gain even more speed because it fell for a longer time? While then going with the same speed but moved up a bit. So I think your concern makes it "gain" energy as it gets more potential energy by getting moved higher "for free". (Assuming other physics are correct, excluding energy loss on the impact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just logically `dy` is a change of `y` over time (`dt`). So it should be:

```
# velocity- acceleration formula
dy += GRAVITY * dt
# change of position
y += dy * dt
```

That works as expected for me.

While:

```
y += dy * dt + (0.5 * GRAVITY * dt ** 2)
```

kinda resembles the position formula, except it should be:

```
y = y_0 * t + (0.5 * GRAVITY * t ** 2)
```

Where `t` is a passed time and `y_0` is the initial position.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me. Do you have any idea why his version in the video (timestamp 5:32 - 5:35) behaved differently with the same formula?

Comment: Well, his formula is incorrect (as I understand it, see my answer for the actual formula. You can read more [here](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/free-fall#:~:text=into%20account%2C%20too%3A-,s%20%3D%20v%E2%82%80t%20%2B%20(1/2)gt%C2%B2,-You%20can%20immediately)). It might be that he uses integers for position and gets them implicitly round down when converting change from double (java does that) so the error disappears. While python just converts the position to float and keeps that error which leads to your issue. But that's a bit of speculation from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Since y > HEIGHT-radius-1 EQUALS 25 > 600-20-1 EQUALS 25 > 579 EQUALS FALSE

dy += GRAVITY * dt EQUALS 0 += 15 * 0.2 EQUALS dy = 3

dy * dt + (0.5 * GRAVITY * dt ** 2) = 3 * 0.2 + (0.5 * 15 * 0.2**2) = 0.6 + ( 7.5 * 0.04) = 0.6 + 0.3 = 0.9

Therefore, y = 0.9 after 1 run. That's why it loses height.

Comment: I mean the height after it bounces. It is supposed to lose height at first but after it bounces, the expected behaviour is that it returns to y=25